# component props returns empty react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have created two components `App` and `leftBar`. I'm getting the `Class component props` in App component. But the same prop is empty in `LeftBar`.

**Index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';


/** Component **/
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/:folders/:actions" component={App}></Route>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import LeftBar from './components/left-bar';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props); //Returns the object
  }

render(){
   return (
     <LeftBar />
   )
  }
}
```

**LeftBar.js**

```
class LeftBar extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            leftBar: ["sarath"]
        }
        console.log(this.props); //this returns empty object {}
    }
}
```

someone point out what was the issue behind this. I want to use props across the multiple components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-router` will not pass props down the way you are hoping.  You need to first pass props to `App` by doing

```
// ...
<Route path="/:folders/:actions" component={props => <App {...this.props} />} />
```

Then you need to pass them along in your child component(s).  **I am including this.state with the assumption you want to use this inside of `LeftBar` but you may remove `{...this.state}` if that is incorrect**:

```
// ...
render () {
    return (
        <LeftBar 
            {...this.props} 
            {...this.state} />
    )
}
```

Comment: I called the console.log after the `leftBar: ["sarath"]` was set. Still I'm getting `{}`.

Comment: yes, because you are setting `this.state = { leftBar: ["sarath"] }`.  `this.state` is not `this.props`

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't assign any props on `<LeftBar />`.

You have to pass the required props to this component as well:

```
render(){
 return (
   <LeftBar {...this.props}/>
 )
}
```